# Error when trying to use "except" statement in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm trying do run the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM products
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = 310
```

I know that in this particular case I should use a simple "...product_id != 310" rather than an except statement, but i need this for other, more complicated queries. The problem is that running that statement leads to an "SQL command not properly ended"-Error. I can't figure out the problem...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using an Oracle version before Oracle 21, you want to use `MINUS` (rather than `EXCEPT`):

```sql
SELECT * FROM products
MINUS
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = 310
```

If you are using Oracle 21, then you can use the [ANSI set operators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/nfcon/details-enhanced-sql-set-operators-282451515.html) `EXCEPT` and `EXCEPT ALL` (which are functionally equivalent to `MINUS` and `MINUS ALL`, respectively).

Comment: Thank you!! Apparently I'm using an older version. Works perfectly with Minus